# Accessing SignalR hub via browser

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, signalr, signalr-hub

How can I access signalr hub via browser? I've created hub named "testhub" (using `HubName` property) and method "Hello" in it, so I want to access it smth like that: `http://serverurl/signalr/testhub/Hello`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SignalR is a real-time messaging framework and so a connection is first established using one of several higher level protocols over HTTP (WebSockets at best, long polling at worst) and then the Hub methods themselves are invoked by passing JSON formatted messages through that higher level protocol.

The example you're describing seems like you're expecting a request/response model and for that you are better off using a REST based technology like ASP.NET MVC or ASP.NET Web API.